# Не работают JS-скрипты в Roundcube

Tags: javascript, roundcube

Суток. Для одного из проектов понадобилось развернуть собственный почтовый сервер и webmail'ом был выбран Roundcube. Однако, ожидая самых разных проблем, столкнулся с такой, что она даже не гуглится.. Полностью не работают скрипты внутри интерфейса. Сначала подумал, что может это Nginx не может обработать их, но, посмотрев консоль браузера, увидел следующее:

[image]

Поискав ответы в русскоязычном и англоязычном гугле, так ничего и не смог найти конкретно по RC. Подкиньте идей как можно исправить или где копать.

Comment: У вас jquery.min.js просто не загрузился или загрузился как-то не так, откройте его по ссылке на него и разбирайтесь дальше

Comment: В том то и проблема, что открывая webmail.example.com/program/js/jquery.min.js генерируется страница из html.php, которая не может собраться до конца по какой-то причине. Там бесконечно сыпятся ошибки в консоль всё с тем же 'Unexpected token <' и рядом других.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя долгое время поисков, наткнулся на [ответ разработчика на github](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/issues/5592) к одному из вопросов. В целом, нужно было запустить **bin/install-jsdeps.sh**.

Answer (score 0):

Требуется подключить jQuery.

Попробуйте добавить статическую ссылку на jQuery из cdn, например:
    https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js

Comment: Если вы внимательно посмотрите на скриншот, то увидите, что он и так подключен